# Developing a text editor with PHP

Tags: php, html, editor

I've started a small project trying to make an online text editor, it WAS going well until the system started overwriting files and adding spaces in unnecessarily. I have one file called editor.php where all the file loading, saving and editing is done.

So this is the opening/closing for the files:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['new'])){
        $filer = substr(md5(microtime()),rand(0,26),6);
        $file_create = $filer.".txt";
        $handle = fopen("files/".$file_create,"w");
        fclose($handle);
        header("Location: editor.php?e=".$filer);
    }

    $file = $_GET['e'];
    $file = basename($file);
    $filename = "files/".$file.".txt";

    $file_get = file_get_contents($filename);

    if(isset($_POST['save'])){
        file_put_contents($filename, $_POST['text']);
    }
?>
```

further down the page I have this in a `<textarea>` tag:

```
<?php
    echo $file_content;
?>
```

This uses the string from the `file_get_contents();`

But when I save, nothing happens, in fact it erases the file, when I load a file there are eight spaces but nothing else.

I know there is another way to do this with `fopen()` and if someone could give me a method to use that, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: If this experiment is ever going to be hosted online, please, please, always sanitize `$file`. Otherwise a remote attacker could open and maybe even edit random files on your server... What if I open the PHP script itself and I insert some malicious code inside?

Answer (score 0):

You have to verify if the $_POST['text'] actually has a content in it.

```
if(isset($_GET['e'])){

    $file = $_GET['e'];
    $file = basename($file);
    $filename = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/files/".$file.".txt";
    $file_get = file_get_contents($filename);

    if(isset($_POST['save'])){
       if(!empty($_POST['text']) && isset($_POST['text']))
       {
          $length = strlen($_POST['text']); 
          if($length > 0)
           file_put_contents($filename, trim($_POST['text']));
          else
           die("No content");
       }

    }
}
```

ALso check if the file exists and its writable. You can use chmod,mkdir and file_exists functions.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at PHP's file modes:  http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php

If you are opening all your files using `fopen()` in `w` mode then your files are being truncated as they are opened.  This is how `w` mode operates.  Try using `a+` or `c+` modes with `fopen()`.

**EDIT**

Also, the `file_put_contents()` will also overwrite file contents unless you sett the `FILE_APPEND` flag, e.g. `file_put_contents($file, $data, FILE_APPEND)`.

Comment: Thanks, I've switched to using fwrite() and that seems to be working. I'm using c+ as the write mode now too. Thank you very much for your help!